# boost bind class function pointer

Tags: c++, boost-bind, boost-function

```
class Foo 
{
    double f1( int x, std::string s1 );
    double f2( int x, SomeClass s2 );
}
```

I want to be able to bind Foo.f1's s1 without an instance of foo to create in essense

```
typedef double (Foo::* MyFooFunc)( int ) 

MyFooFunc func1 = boost::bind( &Foo::f1, _1, _2, "some string" );
MyFooFunc func2 = boost::bind( &Foo::f2, _1, _2, SomeClass );
```

Then I pass func1 and func2 as parameters to other functions, inside which Foo is finally bound:

```
void SomeOtherFunction( MyFooFunc func )
{
     Foo foo;
     boost::function< double (int) > finalFunc =
          boost::bind( func, foo, _1 );
}
```

Questions:
Is this possible?  If yes, 1) how to achieve it? 2) What's the declaration of MyFooFunc?

Comment: It depends on `SomeOtherFunction` is declared. Note that your second typedef is *not* a function pointer, it's  pointer-to-member-function (PTMF), which is an entirely different and incompatible concept. Wrapping everything in `std::function` or `std::tr1::function` or `boost::function` would probably be the most powerful solution.

Comment: There are actually two issues here: 1) binding PTMF without an instance. 2) express the result of the bind as boost function. For 1), I tried boost::bind( &Foo::f1, _1, _2, "hello" ). That didn't work. For 2), I suspect it's boost::function< int (boost::shared_ptr<Foo>,int) >.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
typedef double (Foo::* MyFooFunc)( int );

MyFooFunc func1 = boost::bind( &Foo::f1, _1, _2, "some string" );
```

The result of `boost::bind` is not a pointer to member, so `func1` cannot be initialized as such on the second line. The result of `boost::bind` is an unspecified type (which will depend on the parameters). If you're using C++0x, the simplest way to name the result of a call to `bind` is to use `auto`:

```
auto func1 = boost::bind( &Foo::f1, _1, _2, "some string" );
```

Another simple way (not restricted to C++03) is simply to not name the result, but to use it on the spot:

```
SomeOtherFunction(boost::bind(&Foo::f1, _1, _2, "some string"));
```

Or, you can use type-erasure to store the result of `boost::bind` into a `boost::function`, which you seem to be familiar with. `boost::function<double(Foo&, int)>` is a possibility but not the only choice.

---

We now need to find the appropriate signature for `SomeOtherFunction`: again, a pointer to member can't be initialized from the result of a call to `boost::bind`, so `void SomeOtherFunction(MyFooFunc func);` won't work. You can make the function a template instead:

```
template<typename Func>
void SomeOtherFunction( Func func )
{
     Foo foo;
     boost::function< double (int) > finalFunc =
          boost::bind( func, foo, _1 );
}
```

If a template is not preferrable, then you must use some kind of type-erasure such as, again, `boost::function`.

```
void SomeOtherFunction(boost::function<double(Foo&, int)> const& func);
```

(once again other `boost::function` types are possible depending on details such as passing a ref-to-const as opposed to a ref-to-non-const)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
boost::bind(&Foo::f1, object, _1, _2);
```

`object` is an instance of class Foo.
_1 and _2 are the argument placeholders.

Comment: There's probably just one placeholder, since the OP wants `Foo::f1(int)` I think...

Comment: Note that if `object` is a value and not a pointer, you should do `boost::ref(object)` or `&object`, otherwise binder will operate on a copy.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I want to separate the binding of an instance of Foo (object) and the non uniform parameters (s1,s2) into 2 steps.